# My application crashes when i touch a specific button

Tags: iphone, uibutton, avaudioplayer

Here is the header for my button.

```
IBOutlet UIButton *buttonOneOne;

}

- (IBAction)buttonOneOne:(id)sender; 

@property (nonatomic, retain)   IBOutlet UIButton       *buttonOneOne;
```

This is what i put in my .m file for it

```
- (IBAction)buttonOneOne:(id)sender {

    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"95" ofType:@".wav"];

NSError *activationError = nil;
NSError *audioPlayerInitError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error:&activationError];

NSURL *newURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
AVAudioPlayer *musicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:newURL error:&audioPlayerInitError];

[musicPlayer prepareToPlay];
[musicPlayer setVolume:.8];
[musicPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1]; // -1 means play indefintely
[musicPlayer setDelegate: self];
[musicPlayer play];

}
```

why is it crashing?

Comment: Why @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonOneOne; ? Can you place breakpoint on your IBAction in implementation file.. and also post some crash logs here.

Comment: You should use the code formatting option to make code more readable

Comment: i put the property there because apple did it in their example code im using but i didnt fully understand why it was there, and yes let me do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'` means that the file you're referencing cannot be found.

You should not use the dot when specifying the file extension.

Change `ofType:@".wav"`
to `ofType:@"wav"`

[NSBundle Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: THANK YOU! it works i am so happy :) haha. I was to wrapped up in thinking about NSURL and why AVAudioPlayer didnt seem to be taking it i guess. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should post some console output (possibly a stack trace), it would help us a LOT more.

Possible causes of a crash I can see from this code:

1. Did you `synthesize` your button after decalring an `@property` for it?
2. Does `95.wav` exist in your Xcode Project (have you imported it)?
3. Are you using Interface Builder? If so, check your IB project for old IBOutlets and IBActions, as once you rename a function or whatnot, you're bound to get interface elements pointing to old code.

Comment: yes to 1 and 2, i will do the third and let me go ahead and put in the stack trace, sorry i didnt post that before

Comment: This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 32811.
2011-03-30 16:51:37.779 DubStep[32811:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
2011-03-30 16:51:37.781 DubStep[32811:207] Stack: (
)

Comment: kill
Error resetting ObjC debugger mode: The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB has restored the context to what it was before the call.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal off"
Evaluation of the expression containing the function (gdb_objc_endDebuggerMode) will be abandoned.(gdb)